# How can I display function content in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to display the method contents in my template. I used a `computed` prop to show it, but I get `function () { [native code] }` instead of the actual source code.

Here's the component:

```html
<template>
    <div>{{ showFunction }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        showFunction() {
            return this.confirm.toString();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        confirm() {
            let a = "1";
            return a;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

I want to get the method contents (i.e., `let a = "1"; return a;`), but I get `function () { [native code] }`. How can I get the full function contents?

Comment: you should use return `this.confirm().toString();`

Comment: I got 1 when using it, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue compiles the method definition into `Function` instances, which don't expose their source code as strings. And `this.METHODNAME` gets the compiled `Function` instance.

However, you could access the original method definition through `this.$options.methods.METHODNAME`:

```js
new Vue({
  computed: {
    showFunction() {
      return this.$options.methods.confirm 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    confirm() {/*...*/}
  }
})
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ZEBeWaa?editors=1010)

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString

If the toString() method is called on built-in function objects or a function created by Function.prototype.bind, toString() returns a native function string which looks like

```
"function () {\n    [native code]\n}"
```

Do you have somewhere in your code:

```
this.confirm = this.confirm.bind(this);
```

You would need to store the content of the function before binding it.

```
let myFunction = this.confirm.toString();
this.confirm = this.confirm.bind(this);
```

Comment: I add this content in computed, but still not got the funciton content.
    computed: {
        showFuntion() {
            let myFunction = this.confirm.toString();
            this.confirm = this.confirm.bind(this);
            return this.confirm;
        }
    },